# Configure OLEDB Data Source in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion, oledb, coldfusion-9

I need to access a 3rd Party software database using their propriety OLEDB connector. I've installed their OLEDB software and can confirm using Regedit.

When trying to create a Data Source in the Coldfusion Administrator, I found that the OLEDB data sources have been deprecated since coldfusion MX.

On searching further, I haven't been able to find any alternative way of configuring the data source.

Can you please advise how can I access the OLEDB data source?
Any links or direction would be really appreciated.

Comment: Do they offer any other options, like ODBC or JDBC? Shot in the dark - have you tried connecting through another layer like setting up an ODBC DSN and using ODBC socket?

Comment: @Leigh : They are working on a webAPI at the moment which they have promised to deliver by end of this month. But that will be too late for us to implement/test/production release before the deadline. The OLEDB was the only option they have provided at the moment and I haven't been able to make any headway into it.

Comment: @Leigh : Are you suggesting to setup an ODBC layer using the OLEDB? I'm not sure how to do that. Also, I've tested the ODBC DSN data source and that works fine. I had tried for another test SQL Server db and not this 3rd party database.

Comment: I have not used ODBC or OLEDB in ages.  I thought it might be possible, but more searching suggests I was barking up the wrong tree... If you are using SQL Server, have you tried creating a "linked server" to that database? According to the BOL, it does support OLEDB drivers. Granted, it is not ideal. Linked servers can be finicky, but it is worth a shot at least.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will have to use the 'Other' option value in the datasource driver dropdown. and then provide repective info in the following page. They say that all the OLEDB drivers that might exist will not be listed in the drop down and hence you will have to o the manual way of things.

Further details here" http://www.rvclandtrust.org/CFDOCS/Advanced_ColdFusion_Administration/datasources_ADV_MJS2.html

Comment: That is from CF5. While I have not used OLEDB in years, but AFAIK it no longer applies and "Other" is strictly for JDBC these days.

Comment: Agree with Leigh. JDBC Url is the only option I can see when "Other" is chosen.